# How was countability defined before Cantor?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

We know the Cantor's definition of countable sets.

> A set is countable if there exists an injective function from the set to the set of natural numbers.

I guess that the notion of set must be known (though not formally defined) long before Cantor. If so, then how countable sets were defined (formally or informally) before Cantor.

Comment: Different sizes of infinite sets were not considered before Cantor. Countability and non-countability arguments are his major contribution in creating modern set theory.

Comment: @IttayWeiss So the point you are making is "the notion of countability do not makes sense without the notion of different sizes of infinities".

Comment: Or no need to concern about countability if there are no different sizes of infinities?

Comment: The thing is, no one even talked about infinity, it was a "taboo" in a sense, so this notion wouldn't have made sense to them (and Cantor was at first ridiculed for his ideas)

Comment: The short answer is, it wasn't defined at all.